# show existence of the limit value of some function

Tags: real-analysis

let say $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$
and I need to show  $\lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists but $lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not exist.

Since $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} h\sin(\frac{1}{h})$
I proved $f'(x)$ exists and $g'(x) = \cos(x)$ then exists.

But I dont understand why they saying to prove $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not exist ?

Comment: Can you find a formula for $f'$? Then divide by the formula you have for $g'$, and see what happens to that quotient as $x\to0$.

Comment: You do realize that in order for $f'$ to exist, you need to show that the limit does exist, right?

Comment: if there is cos and sin function together in one formula. its negative and positive everywhere nearby the 0?

Comment: how to prove f(x)/g(x) limit exist first?

Comment: You aren't asked to prove that $f'(x)/g'(x)$ doesn't exist. You're asked to prove that $\lim_{x\to0} f'(x)/g'(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: i guess f'(x) / g'(x) , for this point you can nor find the limit because positive and negative value is everywhere nearby 0. but how do you show this in mathmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere in its domain, and 
$$f'(x)=2x\,\sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)+x^2\,\cos\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)\cdot \bigg(-\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)=2x\,\sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)-\cos\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big).$$
As you obtained, $g'(x)=\cos x$, whose limit is equal to $1$ as $x\to 0$. But as $x\to 0$ the limit of $f'(x)$ does not exist as $2x\,\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$ converges to $0$ while $\cos\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$ is divergent (oscillating between $-1$ and $1$ more and more rapidly). Hence, $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)/g'(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: How do you know 2x sin (1/x) is converge and cos(1/x) is diverge, and oscilating rapidly part ?

Comment: oh I can see it by graph, but can you prove this also? diverge and converge part.